# Giving a formula a specific name in ConTeXt

Tags: equations, context

I would like to name a equation with a specific name ; for example, something like `($A_1$)` ; I tried this structure from the wiki :

```
\startformula
\let\doplaceformulanumber\empty
c^2 = a^2 + b^2   \leqno{\formulanumber}
\stopformula
```

and changed `\formulanumber` with $A_1$, but nothing displays. I also naively tried to replace `\leqno` with `\tag` as I saw on the forum it is used in LaTeX, but in ConTeXt it gave me an "undefined control sequence" error.

Is there a hack to do this in ConTeXt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\starttext
\startplaceformula[title=$A_1$,reference=A1]
\startformula
c^2 = a^2 + b^2   
\stopformula
\stopplaceformula
However, \in[A1] doesn't work. 
%%% Use \!, another kerning or whatever you need
%%% to remove the space after the reference
In such a case you could manually write \in{$A_1$}[A1]\kern-1ex.
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: @A.Licari It is in chapter 5 of [math-mkiv](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/math-mkiv.pdf) (p. 41), but certainly it lacks a lot of detail.

Comment: @A.Licari There's a list in ConTeXt Garden: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Documentation. A manual both in Spanish and English was recenty released and share in the mailing list, too.